# How to move Wubi partition to a whole drive?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 14.04, hard-drive, wubi

I have Sony Vaio laptop with Windows 7 home premium installed by default in it.There was only 1 drive in it,(i.e) the C: drive.It could contain 300 GB of memory.I split the C: drive into another E: drive.That made the laptop have 2 drives with 150 GB storage in each.I decided to put the Ubuntu installation into E: drive.(I mainly did this thing because one of my relatives told that if we keep 2 Operating Softwares in the same drive,it would turn out to be a bit problematic.)Now,I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in the E: drive using wubi.So,it took up only 30 GB of it.Now,I have decided to transfer the wubi partition completely to the E: drive and make it occupy the whole of E: drive without causing any damage to the Windows partition and the C: drive.How can I do this?Any help is greatly appreciated. This is what sudo parted -l shows:
Model: ATA Hitachi HTS54503 (scsi)

Disk /dev/sda: 320GB

Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B

Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags

1      1049kB  10.9GB  10.9GB  primary   ntfs         diag

2      10.9GB  11.0GB  105MB   primary   ntfs         boot

3      11.0GB  166GB   155GB   primary   ntfs

4      166GB   320GB   154GB   extended

5      166GB   316GB   150GB   logical   ntfs

6      316GB   320GB   3940MB  logical

Comment: How many partitions have you uses. Ubuntu does not install to NTFS partitions and must have Linux formatted partitions. Post this sudo parted -l Backup both Windows and all your data in wubi that you want to save. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi It looks like script may not support 14.04 wubi.

Answer (score 0):

Use gparted to create a new root partition and swap partition and then boot wubi and run `wuvi-movi.sh /dev/x /dev/y` where x and y are your new partitions. See [MigrateWubi](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi) for more details.

Comment: When I do that,it shows me this: partition /dev/sda5 must be type 83

Comment: The Linux partition should have type 83. You can change it in gparted.